# Good source for the relationship between absolute magnitude, diameter, and albedo?

Tags: asteroids, absolute-magnitude

In this [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25121/12102) I have rearranged an equation from somewhere, and now I can not relocate the source. My re-aranged form is:

$$M_{Abs} = 5 \left(\log_{10}(1329) -\frac{1}{2}\log_{10}(\text{albedo}) -\log_{10}(D_{km})\right)$$

This is the relationship between the absolute magnitude of an object and its diameter and albedo, assuming it is spherical.

**Question:** What is a good source for any form of this equation to which I can link in my answer?

Comment: This shouldn't be hard to derive. Twice as large = 4 times as bright, double the albedo = double the brightness, convert both to changes in magnitude, and apply to original absolute magnitude.

Comment: Found while reading for another Q: [Wikipedia: Absolute magnitude: Planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude#Planets)

Comment: @MikeG Yep, thanks! While I don't see the exact expression there *verbatim* but I see enough pieces of it in similar form that it is certainly there in spirit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A source of this mathematical expression is:

[**THE ALBEDO DISTRIBUTION OF NEAR EARTH ASTEROIDS, Edward L. Wright et.al.**](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/70302/1/aj_152_4_79.pdf)

This mathematical expression appears in the introduction to this article, and is attributed there to:

"*Application of photometric models to asteroids*", by Bowell, Edward ; Hapke, Bruce ; Domingue, Deborah ; Lumme, Kari ; Peltoniemi, Jouni ; Harris, Alan W. pages 524-556

Best regards.

**Updated**:

The full demonstration of the expression can be found in Appendix A of:

[**Binary asteroid population. Angular momentum content. P. Pravec, A.W. Harris**](https://www.asu.cas.cz/%7Eppravec/pravecharris07.pdf)

$$d \cdot \sqrt p=K\cdot 10^{-\frac H 5}$$

Where:

$$K=2 \ (AU)_{km} \cdot 10^{\frac{V_s}5}$$

The absolute magnitude of Sun is:

$V_s=-26.762$

$(AU)_{km}=149.6\cdot 10^6 \ km$

$$K=2 \cdot 149.6 \cdot 10^6 \cdot 10^{-\frac{26.762}5}=1329 \ km$$

Finally:

$$\boxed{H=5 \log \frac{1329}{d\cdot \sqrt p}}$$

Best regards again.

Comment: $\log_{10}(1329)$ and all. *Excellent!*

Answer (score 4):

The JPL CNEOS
[asteroid size estimator](https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/ast_size_est.html)
and various asteroid albedo papers cite
[Harris and Harris 1997](https://doi.org/10.1006/icar.1996.5664).
That paper is behind a paywall, but
[Stuart and Binzel 2004](http://www.boulder.swri.edu/clark/jssrpb04.pdf)
attribute this formula to it:
$$ H = C - 5 \log_{10} D - 2.5 \log_{10} p_V$$
where $H$ is absolute magnitude, $p_V$ is albedo, and $C$ = 15.618.

Comment: That's numerically equivalent and so it will do, thank you! I'm still going to try to find the source that has the exact expression log${}_{10}$(1329)  in my own quixocity because it bothers me that I've lost a reference (I suspect due to a variant of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309334/303080)).

Comment: It may be trivial, but I finally got my $\log_{10}(1329)$.